# Show tweet in popover on webpage

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asynchronous, bootstrap-popover, twitter-widget

Here's my solution so far: http://codepen.io/ducu/pen/VvwgPq

Problem is that the popover is rendered before the tweet markup is created so there's this resizing effect happening 
(**Edit**: Managed to improve this by having the popover hidden by default and making it visible when tweet content is available).
Tweet border is also removed in the process so the visual effect of that is not nice.

Relevant code here:

```
<a class="tweet" href="https://twitter.com/CodePen/status/638726422027177984" 
rel="popover" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-animation="false" 
data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-tweet-id="638726422027177984">tweet</a>

<script>
// Create Tweets
$(".tweet").each(function() {
  var $tweet = $(this);
  $tweet.popover({
    container: $tweet,
    content: function() {
      var tweetId = String($(this).data("tweet-id"));
      var $target = $("<div>");
      $target.css("width", "245px");
      twttr.widgets.createTweet(tweetId, $target[0], {
          width: "250",
          cards: "hidden",
          conversation: "none"
        })
        .then(function(content) {
          if (typeof content !== 'undefined') {
            var $content = $(content);
            var $doc = $(content.contentDocument);
            $doc.find(".EmbeddedTweet").css("border", "0");
            $doc.find(".EmbeddedTweet-tweet").css("padding", "0");
            $content.parents(".popover").css("visibility", "visible");
          }
        });
      return $target;
    }
  });
  $tweet.on('hide.bs.popover', function () {
    $tweet.find(".popover").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
});
</script>
```

Result is OK-ish, but only works when popover placement is top or bottom because the width of the tweet content is known. If placement is left or right the popover would be shifted away from the trigger element because the height of the tweet content is not known.

How can I show the tweet popover only when available? Thanks for any tips

Comment: The link to codepen is broken, I guess.

Comment: @Roope I see it works, can you try again please?

Comment: @ducu Not working on my side too, maybe because it's private or something?

Comment: I would think you could load all the tweets on page load ? Then they will already be there when the user hovers over them. Right now it looks like they are being reloaded everytime. If for whatever reason you can't load on page load you could still cache the tweets so they wouldn't reload every time.

Comment: @realseanp thanks for the suggestion, tried that, it's too heavy for my use case as I have many tweets on the page

Comment: @Roope I fixed the pen, should be visible now